# How to add 'Delete' button to User Profile template in Django app so the user can delete his/her profile from the app?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have an app login/logout system in which I automatically generate user profiles once user is registered.
My Profile.html looks like this:

```
<div class="col s12">
  <form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
     <fieldset class="">
        <legend class="">Profile Info</legend>
        {{ u_form.username }}
        {{ p_form.postcode }}
     </fieldset>
     <div class="col s6">
       <button class="btn" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
   </form>
 /div>
```

and my profile function from views like this:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user) 
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Account updated!")
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {"u_form": u_form, "p_form": p_form}

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```

How do I add a 'Delete' button and function to allow user delete his/fer own profile to no longer exist in my database?

Comment: All the logic are up to you, you can create a view to handle that. `instance.delete()` will remove the instance from the database, however make sure you really want to delete a user.

Comment: As @Lemayzeur said, the logic is completely up to you. Maybe you could create link to a view that handle the deletion. I think this is one of the simplest way to do what you want to

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be this:

```
@login_required
def delete_profile(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    ProfileModel.objects.get(user=request.user).delete()
    # redirect to some success url
  else:
    # access denied
```

This only delete the profile, not the user. If you want to delete the user you can do the same I did for the profile, though, if you have the relation between the user and the profiles as `delete=CASCADE` you only need to delete the user and the profile will be deleted automatically by the DB.

Later you need add in the urls.py file a url for this view and in your template add a form to go to the view like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The users have a field `is_active` that is recommended for "soft deletion", that means that if you want to remove the user but keep its data and objects related with him/her, you only need set

Comment: It's risky to delete things using a GET request. Suppose an attacker redirects you to the delete link, then you'll have accidentally deleted yourself. Things should be delete over POST. So, you'll have to create a form and the delete button should submit the form.

Comment: Yes @xyres, you are right! I edited the post with your suggestion